# Linq result if null then zero

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How do I write something like this:

```
            int result = database
                .Where(x => x.Name == "Criteria")
                .Sum(x => x.Count)) ?? 0;
```

Where it will return the sum value unless linq does not find anything in which case it will return 0.

EDIT:  The field is not null-able.

EDIT 2:  I am using Entity Framework.

Comment: There are probably better ways, but you could always add `.FirstOrDefault()` to the query.

Comment: FirstOrDefault does not operate on a linq statement already aggregated to int.

Comment: "This method returns zero if source contains no elements."

Comment: Not sure how you could've missed it. It's the first sentence in the Remarks.

Comment: Is this Entity Framework?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You were very close with your original query. You only needed to cast your `Count` variable:

```
int result = database
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Criteria")
    .Sum(x => (int?)x.Count) ?? 0;
```

Doing it this way would be a little more efficient and elegant than wrapping it in a Try/Catch.

I suspect you are using Entity Framework. If you were just using Linq-to-Objects, the solutions everybody else have provided would have worked.

Comment: You are right, I am using Entity Framework, I will give this a try.

Answer (score 5):

This should work fine (no need for ?? 0):

```
var result = database
.Where(x => x.Name == "Criteria")
.Sum(x => x.Count))
```

Unless you want to check if x itself is null or not:

```
var result = database
.Where(x => x != null)
.Where(x => x.Name == "Criteria")
.Sum(x => x.Count))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just write:

```
int result = database
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Criteria")
            .Sum(x => x.Count));
```

The `Enumerable.Sum` method already returns zero on no results.  From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184.aspx):

> returns zero if source contains no elements.

Comment: I think this is only for the IEnumerable version not the IQueriable. The IQueriable version returns null and the solution with '?? 0' works.

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine:

```
var result = database.Where(x => x.Name == "Criteria").Sum(x => x.Count));
```

If no elements are returned by the `Where` function then the `Sum` function will return 0.

All of the Linq functions that return an `IEnumerable<T>` will return an empty collection instead of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Use  the Aggregate extension method where 0 is a seed value

```
int sum = database.Where(x=>x.Name == "Criteria")
                  .Aggregate(0, (total, next) => total +=next);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a way that no one is going to like but garrantee to work 100% of the time, behold!

```
        int result = 0;
        try{
            result  = database
                .Where(x => x.Name == "Criteria")
                .Sum(x => x.Count));
        } catch (Exception e){ }
```